# Is it possible for a person to know now if he/she is saved and would be inheriting eternal life in the hereafter as per the Biblical teachings?

Tags: bible, soteriology, heaven, assurance-of-salvation

In general those who are pious in following any religion look forward to a better place hereafter. Even in Islam pious people without exception hope for a place in Janna.

My question is to the Bible believing Christians. Is it possible for any pious Christian to know in this world if he/she would definitely be granted a place in Paradise as per the teachings of the Bible? If so, what is the evidence in the Bible?

Comment: Of course it is. Many people testify to the experience. The evidence is the way they live their lives. Have you not met any such persons ? Or read about them ?

Comment: I have edited my question for more clarity.

Comment: It's not possible to "know" "definitely". One can only have faith and hope. To definitely know for sure that one will be meeting Jesus at his return is vanity, to presume God's decisions, to exalt oneself above others.  Imagine a Christian and a Muslim each sincerely believing themselves saved and believing the other not.  At least one of them must be wrong.

Comment: Again, I think you will need to ask this question of a particular _named_ group of self-identifying Christians. There is a wide spectrum of varied understanding within what calls itself 'Christian.

Comment: _I know whom I have believed, and am persuaded that he is able to keep that which I have committed unto him against that day._ 2 Timothy 1:12. _Henceforth there is laid up for me a crown of righteousness, which the Lord, the righteous judge, shall give me at that day: and not to me only, **but unto all them also that love his appearing**._ 2 Timothy 4:8.

Comment: @Ray Butterworth. It's not about what one thinks or hopes about oneself or about others. It's what the Scriptures say matters in this issue. So, what's the evidence as per the Bible is the question to the Bible believing Christians.

Comment: Different groups of "Bible believing" Christians have different answers.  The topic is called "assurance of salvation". You can read those different views in [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assurance_(theology)) and a common Reformed view in [GotQuestions](https://www.gotquestions.org/signs-saving-faith.html).

Comment: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/79215/23657  Related

Comment: 3 Seek the Lord, all you humble of the land,
    you who do what he commands.
Seek righteousness, seek humility;
    perhaps you will be sheltered
    on the day of the Lord’s anger.    Zephaniah 2:3.

Comment: .,”Bible believing Christian’s”  is too broad in scope.  Perhaps ask two such questions. One scoped at OSAS believers and oneAt OSAS Deniers.

Answer (score 3):

There is an important difference between hoping, and knowing (while in this world, regarding a place in Janna or Paradise). To hope is not to know. And there are two important problems. What pious, Bible-believing Christians call "the assurance of salvation", many others call presumptuousness, because they do not have such an assurance. The problem is explaining what enables some to speak confidently of being with Christ in glory after they have died, and how others interpret the many Bible promises that are meant to assure Christians of this.

Problem #1 cannot be solved by listing the many scriptures in the Bible that speak of future glory as assured, but you have asked for that, so I will list a small sample of some of the texts (hoping that other answers will provide ones I've missed out due to the huge amount of space a full list would take up):

> “And as many as were *ordained to eternal life* believed.” Acts 13:48
>
> “And you were made alive, you who were dead in your transgressions and
> sins in which you used to live… But because of his great love for us,
> God, who is rich in mercy, *made us alive with Christ even when we
> were dead in transgressions* – it is by grace you have been saved… For
> it is by grace you are saved, through faith – and this not from
> yourselves, *it is the gift of God – not by works*, so that no-one can
> boast. For we are God’s workmanship, created in Christ Jesus to do
> good works which God prepared in advance for us to do.” Ephesians
> 2:1-10
>
> “Being confident of this, that *he who began a good work in you will
> carry it on to completion* until the day of Christ Jesus... now as always, Christ will be exalted in my body, whether by life or by death. For to me, to live is Christ and to die is gain... Yet what shall I choose? I do not know! I am torn between the two; I desire to depart and be with Christ, which is better by far. ” Philippians 1:5 & 20-24
>
> “For God did not appoint us to suffer wrath but to receive salvation
> through our Lord Jesus Christ…  May God himself, the God of peace,
> sanctify you through and through. May your whole spirit, soul and body
> *be kept blameless at the coming of our Lord Jesus Christ. The one who calls you is faithful and he will do it*.” 1 Thessalonians 5:9 & 22-24
>
> *“He will keep you strong to the end, so that you will be blameless on the day of our Lord Jesus Christ. God, who has called you into
> fellowship with his Son Jesus Christ our Lord, is faithful*.” 1
> Corinthians 1:8-9
>
> “By one sacrifice *he has made perfect for ever those who are being
> made holy*.” Hebrews 10:14
>
> "Now we know that *if the earthly tent we live in is destroyed, we
> have a building from God, an eternal house in heaven*... Now it is
> *God who has made us for this very purpose and has given us the Spirit as a deposit, guaranteeing what is to come. Therefore we are always
> confident* and know that as long as we are at home in the body we are
> away from the Lord. We live by faith, not by sight. We are
> confident..."  [All italics mine.]

Problem #2 prevents those who do not have this confidence in the promises and assurances of God from understanding why others do. They accept interpretations of all those promises that they are provisional, dependent on the believer not slipping up badly enough before death, so as to forfeit everything. And, to be fair, there are, indeed some Bible texts that they protest show this. For example, Philippians 2:12 & Hebrews 10:26-39 to mention but two. To save the question degenerating into trading proof-texts, **there is a simple solution to both problems**.

The solution lies in knowing what the Bible means when it says **the Holy Spirit has been given to saved believers, as a guarantee** that they are now adopted into God's family, and are sons who will obtain the promised heavenly inheritance. Romans chapter 8 explains this fully. Sadly, many professed Christians have no idea what that chapter means, experientially, because they are not anointed, or indwelt, with the Holy Spirit. Many have been told that such an assurance is limited to a tiny number of people, or they have been told that it's a provisional guarantee (which is a contradiction in terms) and think no further, because they don't have that assurance from the Holy Spirit.

There's nothing anybody can do about this. You either have the Holy Spirit's assurance, or you don't. I cannot offer you proofs. I cannot argue and argue about proof-texts, nor would I. That is futile. Yet that is what this question will likely descend into. So, let people call the assured saints 'presumptuous' if they want. That won't change the material fact of them being securely in Christ's hand, which is the same as being in the hand of the Father (as Jesus said, John 10:27-30). They know that nothing can now separate them from the love of God in Christ (Romans 8:29-35).

Comment: You have provided quite a bit of Scriptural evidence for the assurance. That answers the question itself. If any so-called Christian explains those Scriptures away so as not to have assurance now that's their personal view. However, now two important sub-questions emerge here. One, even if the assurance is conditional, it does exist in that form as far as the Christian Scriptures are concerned, doesn't it? Two, what are the possible experiential evidences that one can use as litmus test for that assurance?

Comment: @TeluguBeliever  The two sub-questions you suggest require posting as a fresh item because this site is for asking one question at a time. It is not for starting a discussion on a broad topic.  All I would add is,  "We are not of them that draw back unto perdition but are of them that believe to the saving of the soul."
"When ye seek me with all your heart - ye will find me."
"All the promises of God are yea and amen in Christ Jesus."

Comment: I would say to your comment, Amen!

Comment: A valuable addition to your list of Scriptures:  1 John 5:13.  +1